# Restoring a database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Say I have a database `Live` on some instance. I have created a backup of it and now I need to restore it into a new database named `Dev`.
In `SSMS` I am choosing a device `Live.bak`, then in destination I am changing the name to `Dev` and in `Files` tab I see that database and log files are also renamed `Dev.mdf` and `Dev_log.ldf`. When I proceed the `Live` database changes its status to `Restoring`.

Now I tried to uncheck tail log option and it restored normally. Is it safe way to restore the database? I mean I don't want any changes to `Live`. Why it tries to restore `Live` database. I am confused.

Comment: If you could supply screen shots, this might help in determining where your issue is. If you do it correctly then the status of the `Live` database should not change to `Restoring`, because then you are restoring the `Live` database.

Comment: I suggest writing a `RESTORE DATABASE Dev...` script instead of pointing and clicking in the GUI.

Comment: Yeah, if the `Live` database changes status to `Restoring`, then you've done something wrong, you probably don't have the destination set properly. In this scenario, you should instead see a *new* database named `Dev` appear with status `Restoring`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, can you please explain why?
I asked local admin about this case and he said, that this happens because of a tail log. So the live database is changing its status because Dev database needs a data from Live that is not in the backup. I mean if I made a bak at 10 am and restoring it to Dev at 12am, live db is locked so this 2 hour data is also added to Dev.

Comment: My reason is because you can’t always be sure what the GUI is doing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the SSMS GUI interface to restore databases, you should create a T-SQL script for the restore statement.

This serves two purposes:

1. You can confirm the target database name, the location of the restored database files, etc prior to the start of the restore.
2. You can re-run the restore statement as needed in future without re-using the GUI.  This ensures you do the restore the same way each time.

You can create a script from the "Restore Database" dialog-box as show in this screenshot:

[image]

This will generate a restore statement like the one below, which I've wrapped for readability:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [test_master_restore] 
FROM  DISK = N'D:\SQLServer\Backups\master_db.bak' WITH  FILE = 1
    ,  MOVE N'master' TO N'D:\SQLServer\MV\MSSQL10_50.MV\MSSQL\DATA\test_master_restore.mdf'
    ,  NOUNLOAD
    ,  STATS = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be safer to restore the database via script, just to be sure you know what is -- and is not -- happening to your databases.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Dev] 
FROM DISK = 'Path\to\Full-Backup\Live-Full-Backup.bak' 
WITH Recovery, --make this NORecovery if you want to apply .trn files after
STATS=10 
, MOVE '<DataFileLogicalName>' TO 'Path\Dev_01.mdf',  
  MOVE '<LogFileLogicalName>' TO 'Path\Log_01.ldf' ;
```

you'll need to fix the path statements and the logical names.