# how to script out database users and permissions in all user databases in the instance

Tags: sql-server, permissions, database-user

Can anyone help, please?

I would like to use Steve Kusen's script at [Script DB Level Permissions v4.3](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/script-db-level-permissions-v4-3)

to loop through all the user databases automatically, using Aaron Bertrand's sp_ineachdb. Has anyone got this to work? Kindly advise on how to do it, please.

Thank you

Comment: Please update your post with the [correct script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295142/how-to-script-out-database-users-and-permissions-in-all-user-databases-in-the-in#comment576837_295162)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only tested this in

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU24) (KB5001228) - 14.0.3391.2 (X64)
Apr 28 2021 10:32:18
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

**Step 1**

Create a stored procedure from the code you want to execute in each database. You will need to do it in the master database and start with sp_. [Why?](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1612/creating-your-own-sql-server-system-stored-procedures/)

```
USE [master];
GO

create procedure dbo.sp_ScriptOutPermission as begin
    /*

This script will script the role members for all roles on the database.

This is useful for scripting permissions in a development environment before refreshing
   development with a copy of production.  This will allow us to easily ensure
   development permissions are not lost during a prod to dev restoration. 

URL for this script: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/login/138379/
    Old URL http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Security/71562/  -- Periodically, updates are made to this script so check out the URL for updates.
   
Author: S. Kusen

Updates:
2017-07-10 v4.3:
I was unable to easily get this into a stored procedure / powershell script, so this update includes the changes/updates noted here:
    1. Incorporated Andrew G's updates from previous feedback (Much delayed to being updated on the main script page).  Thanks Andrew!
    2. danmeskel2002 recommended a fix for the SID issue for "SQL User without login".   
        Changed this line:
            SID = '' + CONVERT(varchar(1000), sid) 
            to
            SID = '' + CONVERT(varchar(1000), sid, 1)

2016-10-31:  AG 1. Added extended stored procedures and system object permissions for master database in OBJECT LEVEL PERMISSIONS area by removing join to sys.objects and using functions instead
            2. Added EXISTS check to all statements
            3. Added CREATE ROLE before adding principals to roles 

2016-08-25:  AG 1. Remove default database being specified for an AD group user as this option causes a failure on create

2015-08-21:
         1. Modified section 3.1 to load to a temp table and populate different users based on an error in 2005/2008 because of the update made for contained databases.  Thanks to Andrew G for pointing that out.
         2. Altered section 4.1 to include COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT in the join statement.  Thanks to Andrew G and PHXHoward for pointing that out.


2015-06-30: 
         1. Re-numbered all sections based on additional updates being added inline.
         2. Added sections 8, 8.1; From Eddict, user defined types needed to be added.
         3. Added sections 4, 4.1; From nhaberl, for orphaned users mapping (if logins don't exist, they will not be created by this script).
         4. Updated section 3.1; From nhaberl, updated to include a default schema of dbo. 

2014-07-25: Fix pointed out by virgo for where logins are mapped to users that are a different name.  Changed ***+ ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name]) +*** to ***+ ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(suser_sname([sid])) +***.

2014-01-24: Updated to account for 2012 contained db users

2012-05-14: Incorporated a fix pointed out by aruopna for Schema-level permissions.

2010-01-20:   Turned statements into a cursor and then using print statements to make it easier to 
      copy/paste into a query window.
      Added support for schema level permissions


Thanks to wsoranno@winona.edu and choffman for the recommendations.

*/
SET NOCOUNT ON


/*Prep statements*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tbl_db_principals_statements') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##tbl_db_principals_statements 
CREATE TABLE ##tbl_db_principals_statements (stmt varchar(max), result_order decimal(4,1))
IF ((SELECT SUBSTRING(convert(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')), 1, charindex('.',convert(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))-1)) > 10)
EXEC ('
INSERT INTO ##tbl_db_principals_statements (stmt, result_order)
   SELECT   
      CASE WHEN rm.authentication_type IN (2, 0) /* 2=contained database user with password, 0 =user without login; create users without logins*/ THEN (''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = '' + SPACE(1) + '''''''' + [name] + '''''''' + '') BEGIN CREATE USER '' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME([name]) + '' WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = '' + QUOTENAME([default_schema_name]) + SPACE(1) + '', SID = '' + CONVERT(varchar(1000), sid, 1) + SPACE(1) + '' END; '')
         ELSE (''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = '' + SPACE(1) + '''''''' + [name] + '''''''' + '') BEGIN CREATE USER '' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME([name]) + '' FOR LOGIN '' + QUOTENAME(suser_sname([sid])) + CASE WHEN [type] <>''G'' THEN '' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = '' + QUOTENAME(ISNULL([default_schema_name], ''dbo'')) ELSE '''' END + SPACE(1) + ''END; '') 
         END AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
         3.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
   FROM   sys.database_principals AS rm
   WHERE [type] IN (''U'', ''S'', ''G'') /* windows users, sql users, windows groups */
     AND NAME <> ''guest''')

ELSE IF ((SELECT SUBSTRING(convert(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')), 1, charindex('.',convert(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))-1)) IN (9,10))
EXEC ('
INSERT INTO ##tbl_db_principals_statements (stmt, result_order)
   SELECT   (''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = '' + SPACE(1) + '''''''' + [name] + '''''''' + '') BEGIN CREATE USER '' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME([name]) + '' FOR LOGIN '' + QUOTENAME(suser_sname([sid])) + CASE WHEN [type] <>''G'' THEN '' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = '' + QUOTENAME(ISNULL([default_schema_name], ''dbo'')) ELSE '''' END + SPACE(1) + ''END; '') AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
         3.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
   FROM   sys.database_principals AS rm
   WHERE [type] IN (''U'', ''S'', ''G'') /* windows users, sql users, windows groups */
   AND NAME <> ''guest''')

--SELECT * FROM ##tbl_db_principals_statements




DECLARE 
    @sql VARCHAR(2048)
    ,@sort INT 

DECLARE tmp CURSOR FOR


/*********************************************/
/*********   DB CONTEXT STATEMENT    *********/
/*********************************************/
SELECT '-- [-- DB CONTEXT --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
UNION
SELECT   'USE' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      1.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]

UNION

SELECT '' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      2 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]

UNION

/*********************************************/
/*********     DB USER CREATION      *********/
/*********************************************/

   SELECT '-- [-- DB USERS --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
         3 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
   UNION

   SELECT   
      [stmt],
         3.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
   FROM   ##tbl_db_principals_statements
   --WHERE [type] IN ('U', 'S', 'G') -- windows users, sql users, windows groups
   WHERE [stmt] IS NOT NULL

UNION

/*********************************************/
/*********    MAP ORPHANED USERS     *********/
/*********************************************/

SELECT '-- [-- ORPHANED USERS --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      4 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
UNION
SELECT   'ALTER USER [' + rm.name + '] WITH LOGIN = [' + rm.name + ']',
      4.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
FROM   sys.database_principals AS rm
 Inner JOIN sys.server_principals as sp
 ON rm.name = sp.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT and rm.sid <> sp.sid
WHERE rm.[type] IN ('U', 'S', 'G') -- windows users, sql users, windows groups
 AND rm.name NOT IN ('dbo', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys', 'MS_DataCollectorInternalUser')

UNION

/*********************************************/
/*********    DB ROLE PERMISSIONS    *********/
/*********************************************/
SELECT '-- [-- DB ROLES --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      5 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
UNION

SELECT   'IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(' + QUOTENAME([name],'''') COLLATE database_default + ') IS NULL' + SPACE(1) + 'CREATE ROLE'
   + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME([name]),
      5.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE [type] ='R' -- R = Role
   AND [is_fixed_role] = 0
--ORDER BY [name] ASC
UNION

SELECT   'IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(rm.member_principal_id),'''') COLLATE database_default + ') IS NOT NULL' + SPACE(1) + 'EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename ='
   + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(rm.role_principal_id), '''') COLLATE database_default + ', @membername =' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(rm.member_principal_id), '''') COLLATE database_default AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      5.2 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
FROM   sys.database_role_members AS rm
WHERE   USER_NAME(rm.member_principal_id) IN (   
                                    --get user names on the database
                                    SELECT [name]
                                    FROM sys.database_principals
                                    WHERE [principal_id] > 4 -- 0 to 4 are system users/schemas
                                    and [type] IN ('G', 'S', 'U') -- S = SQL user, U = Windows user, G = Windows group
                                   )
--ORDER BY rm.role_principal_id ASC


UNION

SELECT '' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      7 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]

UNION

/*********************************************/
/*********  OBJECT LEVEL PERMISSIONS *********/
/*********************************************/
SELECT '-- [-- OBJECT LEVEL PERMISSIONS --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      7.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
UNION
SELECT   'IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(usr.principal_id),'''') COLLATE database_default + ') IS NOT NULL' + SPACE(1) +
      CASE 
         WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN perm.state_desc 
         ELSE 'GRANT'
      END
      + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name + SPACE(1) + 'ON ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(perm.major_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id)) --select, execute, etc on specific objects
      + CASE
            WHEN cl.column_id IS NULL THEN SPACE(0)
            ELSE '(' + QUOTENAME(cl.name) + ')'
        END
      + SPACE(1) + 'TO' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(usr.principal_id)) COLLATE database_default
      + CASE 
            WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN SPACE(0)
            ELSE SPACE(1) + 'WITH GRANT OPTION'
        END
         AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      7.2 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
FROM   
   sys.database_permissions AS perm

   /* No join to sys.objects as it excludes system objects such as extended stored procedures */
   /*   INNER JOIN
   sys.objects AS obj
         ON perm.major_id = obj.[object_id]
   */
      INNER JOIN
   sys.database_principals AS usr
         ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
      LEFT JOIN
   sys.columns AS cl
         ON cl.column_id = perm.minor_id AND cl.[object_id] = perm.major_id
  WHERE /* Include System objects when scripting permissions for master, exclude elsewhere */
      (    DB_NAME() <> 'master' AND perm.major_id IN (SELECT [object_id] FROM sys.objects WHERE type NOT IN ('S'))
        OR DB_NAME() =  'master'
        ) 
                      
      
         
--WHERE   usr.name = @OldUser
--ORDER BY perm.permission_name ASC, perm.state_desc ASC


UNION

/*********************************************/
/*********  TYPE LEVEL PERMISSIONS *********/
/*********************************************/
SELECT '-- [-- TYPE LEVEL PERMISSIONS --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
        8 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
UNION
SELECT  'IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(usr.principal_id),'''') COLLATE database_default + ') IS NOT NULL' + SPACE(1) +
      CASE 
            WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN perm.state_desc 
            ELSE 'GRANT'
        END
        + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name + SPACE(1) + 'ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(tp.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(tp.name) --select, execute, etc on specific objects
        + SPACE(1) + 'TO' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(usr.principal_id)) COLLATE database_default
        + CASE 
                WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN SPACE(0)
                ELSE SPACE(1) + 'WITH GRANT OPTION'
          END
            AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
        8.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
FROM    
    sys.database_permissions AS perm
        INNER JOIN
    sys.types AS tp
            ON perm.major_id = tp.user_type_id
        INNER JOIN
    sys.database_principals AS usr
            ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id


UNION

SELECT '' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
   9 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]

UNION

/*********************************************/
/*********    DB LEVEL PERMISSIONS   *********/
/*********************************************/
SELECT '-- [--DB LEVEL PERMISSIONS --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      10 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
UNION
SELECT   'IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(usr.principal_id),'''') COLLATE database_default + ') IS NOT NULL' + SPACE(1) +
      CASE 
         WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN perm.state_desc --W=Grant With Grant Option
         ELSE 'GRANT'
      END
   + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name --CONNECT, etc
   + SPACE(1) + 'TO' + SPACE(1) + '[' + USER_NAME(usr.principal_id) + ']' COLLATE database_default --TO <user name>
   + CASE 
         WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN SPACE(0) 
         ELSE SPACE(1) + 'WITH GRANT OPTION' 
     END
      AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      10.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
FROM   sys.database_permissions AS perm
   INNER JOIN
   sys.database_principals AS usr
   ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
--WHERE   usr.name = @OldUser

WHERE   [perm].[major_id] = 0
   AND [usr].[principal_id] > 4 -- 0 to 4 are system users/schemas
   AND [usr].[type] IN ('G', 'S', 'U') -- S = SQL user, U = Windows user, G = Windows group

UNION

SELECT '' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      11 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]

UNION 

SELECT '-- [--DB LEVEL SCHEMA PERMISSIONS --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      12 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
UNION
SELECT   'IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id),'''') COLLATE database_default + ') IS NOT NULL' + SPACE(1) +
         CASE
         WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN perm.state_desc --W=Grant With Grant Option
         ELSE 'GRANT'
         END
            + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name --CONNECT, etc
            + SPACE(1) + 'ON' + SPACE(1) + class_desc + '::' COLLATE database_default --TO <user name>
            + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(major_id))
            + SPACE(1) + 'TO' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id)) COLLATE database_default
            + CASE
               WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN SPACE(0)
               ELSE SPACE(1) + 'WITH GRANT OPTION'
               END
         AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --],
      12.1 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]
from sys.database_permissions AS perm
   inner join sys.schemas s
      on perm.major_id = s.schema_id
   inner join sys.database_principals dbprin
      on perm.grantee_principal_id = dbprin.principal_id
WHERE class = 3 --class 3 = schema

ORDER BY [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --]


OPEN tmp
FETCH NEXT FROM tmp INTO @sql, @sort
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        PRINT @sql
        FETCH NEXT FROM tmp INTO @sql, @sort    
END

CLOSE tmp
DEALLOCATE tmp 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tbl_db_principals_statements') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##tbl_db_principals_statements
END
GO
```

**Step 2**

Marking Stored Procedure as System Object

```
USE [master];
GO
EXECUTE sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_ScriptOutPermission;
GO
```

**Step 3**

Deploy Aaron Bertrand's sp_ineachdb in the Master database and mark it as a system object

```
USE [master];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ineachdb
  @command nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @context nvarchar(150),
          @sx      nvarchar(18) = N'.sys.sp_executesql',
          @db      sysname;
  CREATE TABLE #dbs(name sysname PRIMARY KEY);

  INSERT #dbs(name) SELECT QUOTENAME(name) 
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE [state] <= 0 -- accessible
    AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'UserAccess') <> 'SINGLE_USER' 
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

  DECLARE dbs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT name, name + @sx FROM #dbs;

  OPEN dbs;

  FETCH NEXT FROM dbs INTO @db, @context;

  DECLARE @msg nvarchar(512) = N'Could not run against %s : %s.',
          @err nvarchar(max);

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
  BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC @context @command = @command;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      SET @err = ERROR_MESSAGE();
      RAISERROR(@msg, 1, 0, @db, @err);
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM dbs INTO @db, @context;
  END

  CLOSE dbs; DEALLOCATE dbs;

END
GO

EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject N'sp_ineachdb'; 
GO
```

**Step 4**

Execute in all database

```
EXEC dbo.sp_ineachdb N'EXEC sp_ScriptOutPermission;';
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time!! Wow, that is so kind of you. I am unable to test it right now but will feed back as soon as I'm able. What you have done is so clear and I'm sure it will work, but i will feed back. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem. That way, others can find it easily and get benefited.

Comment: first let me apologise big time for the delay in giving a feedback, my sincere apologies please, it was an unavoidable situation. Yes, the scripts work brilliantly well, thank you so much for your time, I am most appreciative. I have accepted the answer as correct and did the upvoting the last time. Thanks again, I'm very grateful

Answer (score 2):

This might help in some way - check out the `Permissions - ScriptLoginPermissions.sql` here:

https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools

It creates stored procedure named `ScriptLoginPermissions`, you deploy it to any user database and then execute and supply login's name as parameter

```
exec ScriptLoginPermissions 'LoginName'
```

And it will script specified login's permissions in all user databases (if login has any users associated with it in user databases) + server-level permissions

Comment: thank you so much for your time! As you say, it might not help with the exact issue I'm currently trying to resolve but it will surely help in some way, thank you so much, I appreciate your helpful input

Comment: @PTL_SQL you welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The script you are pointing to only works from SQL Server 2005-2016.

There is a new one compatible with the latest version [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/script-db-level-permissions-v4-3).

Comment: thanks, yes that's the one I meant http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/login/138379/

Comment: @PTL_SQL, that works for me, where are you stuck?

Comment: thank you for your time, much appreciated. I'm trying to use Aaron's sp_ineachdb with Steve's script to loop  through all the user databases and script out the users and their permissions.  The script works for one database at a time but I've not yet figured out how to use it for multiple databases in a script. Thank you