# Whether to fix orphan using alter user or sp_change_users_login?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

What is the correct way to fix orphan user:

```
sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', 
@UserNamePattern='TestUser1', 
@LoginName='TestUser1'
```

Or

```
ALTER USER TestUser1 WITH LOGIN=TestUser1
```

Both fix the orphan user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states about sp_change_users_login:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER USER instead.

Link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql